# Getting value from other parallel object

Tags: javascript, object

I have object with 2 objects inside :

```
o = {  
  center : { x:1, y:1 },  
  startPosition : {x:center.x, y:center.y}  
}
```

And of course I have an error :

```
ReferenceError: center is not defined
```

How to get value of center inside startPosition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    o = {  
      center : { x:1, y:1 }
    }
  o.startPosition = {x:o.center.x, y:o.center.y}
```

Comment: Could You tell my why my example doesn't work ? What about scoping? JS has functional scope and there is no function.

Comment: @Tukkan. because you trying to read center which is not available. you can not read a property of object without its object. also you can not use o.center as o is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
o = {};
o.center = { x:1, y:1 };
o.startPosition = { x:o.center.x, y:o.center.y };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with:

```
var o = {
    center: {
        'x':1, 
        'y':1
    }
};
o.startPosition = { 
    'x': o.center.x, 
    'y': o.center.y
};
console.log(o.startPosition.y);
```